# Is there a way to add maven dependencies while using the maven-jlink-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jodatime, java-9, jlink

I'm using this [Github project](https://github.com/khmarbaise/jdk9-jlink-jmod-example/tree/master/maven-example-only-jars) to get exposed to the new modular features in Java 9. I would like to add dependencies to the project and be able to build a native image. However, when I try to add a new dependency to the pom.xml, and add the requires statement to the module-info.java, I get a the following error from the maven-jlink-plugin:

```
Error: module-info.class not found for joda.time module
```

I'm trying to use this as a proof of concept that I can deploy images using the new linking phase, but naturally I need to be able to have external dependencies and I need to use maven (work constraint).

Changes to mod-jar/pom.xml

```
...
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
...
```

mod-jar/module-info.java

```
module com.soebes.nine.jar {
  requires java.base;
  requires joda.time;
  exports com.soebes.example.nine.jar;
}
```

Logs:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink (default-jlink) @ mod-jlink ---
[INFO] Toolchain in maven-jlink-plugin: jlink [ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink ]
[INFO] The following dependencies will be linked into the runtime image:
[INFO]  -> module: com.soebes.nine.one ( /Users/sebastianrestrepo/Projects/jdk9-jlink-jmod-example/maven-example/mod-1/target/jmods/com.soebes.nine.one.jmod )
[INFO]  -> module: com.soebes.nine.two ( /Users/sebastianrestrepo/Projects/jdk9-jlink-jmod-example/maven-example/mod-2/target/jmods/com.soebes.nine.two.jmod )
[INFO]  -> module: com.soebes.nine.jar ( /Users/sebastianrestrepo/Projects/jdk9-jlink-jmod-example/maven-example/mod-jar/target/com.soebes.nine.jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: joda.time ( /Users/sebastianrestrepo/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9/joda-time-2.9.9.jar )
[ERROR] 
Error: module-info.class not found for joda.time module
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  1.460 s]
[INFO] com.soebes.nine.one ................................ SUCCESS [  2.022 s]
[INFO] com.soebes.nine.two ................................ SUCCESS [  1.392 s]
[INFO] com.soebes.nine.jar ................................ SUCCESS [  1.388 s]
[INFO] mod-jlink .......................................... FAILURE [  1.061 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.911 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-03T15:27:35-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/981M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink (default-jlink) on project mod-jlink:
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: The logs are from running mvn clean package in the maven-example directory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has [not much to do with the plugin I believe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882108/how-to-find-automatic-modules-with-javapackager/46883102#46883102). Module `joda.time` in your case seems to be an *automatic module*.

The [`jlink` tool does not support linking of automatic modules](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2016-July/008559.html) because they can rely on the arbitrary content of the classpath, which goes against the idea of a self-contained Java runtime.

So there are two ways to fix this probably :-

- (you don't own the jar) Temporarily go ahead create a `module-info.java`[you could [use `jdeps` tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47080726/1746118) for it] and update the jar[using `jar` tool] with the corresponding compiled class as in projects under Java 9.
- (you own the dependency) Permanently migrate the jar to Java 9 itself, where it would consist of the `module-info.class` by itself after being compiled and packaged.

Comment: Though I would await the owner of the repo you cloned to come up with something he has already tried to overcome the same. [@khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm having some issues adding a `module-info.java` to the existing jar. I can add the java file to the jar, but I think I need it to be a .class file. However, I can't seem to compile the module-info.java file because the compiler is saying the `org.joda.time` does not exist. Any suggestions?

Comment: In order to compile the module-info.java then you need to extract the contents of the JAR to a directory. Then compile the module-info.java with the output directory (-d) set to the directory where you extracted the contents. Doing this for a JAR file that you don't maintain is of course a bit uncool, better to get the maintainer of the library to migrate it to an explicit module.

Comment: Joda-Time will have a module-info.class added at some point, you'll just have to lookout for releases. The module name will be `org.joda.time`.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to wait for the release of Joda-Time which contains the `module-info.java` file....

Comment: @AlanBateman but adding module-info.java in you source code requires that you compiles with java 9 (or higher) and apparently you can't set the target vm to lower than 9 then. So I can understand a lot of library maintainers are not doing it.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the [ModiTect Maven plug-in](https://github.com/moditect/moditect) to add a module descriptor to the JAR and create a modular runtime image with that module.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of ModiTect.

Comment: +1 for Moditect: allows libraries that can not move to JDK 9+ to still produce valid module info really nicely, esp. from Maven.

Comment: Can ModiTect be used to generate module-info and patch all automatic modules in a single step? Or do you have to configure each dependency separately?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in one of my projects. First, I tried the `moditect-maven-plugin`, which worked great! However, with this plugin you have to configure each dependency that is missing a module descriptor separately. **If you have many dependencies missing a module descriptor, this can get cumbersome.**

Therefore, I decided to develop a new maven plugin, the `jigsaw-maven-plugin` (see https://github.com/ghackenberg/jigsaw-maven-plugin). **The plugin provides three goals for patching *all* unnamed modules (see Step 3) as well as linking and packaging these modules (see Steps 4 and 5)**.

*Before patching, linking, and packaging,* you need to build the project JAR (see Step 1) in and copy the project dependencies (see Step 2) to a common location (e.g. `${project.build.directory}/modules`). Maybe you can use the following build plugin configurations to get started (see [GitHub page](https://github.com/ghackenberg/jigsaw-maven-plugin) for more details):

**Step 1: Build archive**

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Step 2: Copy dependencies**

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory> 
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Step 3: Patch *all* unnamed modules**

Search for JARs in `modulePath` missing a module descriptor, generate missing module descriptors using `jdeps` and `javac`, and add them to respective JARs using `java.util.zip`.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.github.ghackenberg</groupId>
  <artifactId>jigsaw-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>patch</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <modulePath>${project.build.directory}/modules</modulePath>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Step 4: Link modules**

Link modules using `jlink`.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.github.ghackenberg</groupId>
  <artifactId>jigsaw-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>link</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <modulePath>${project.build.directory}/modules</modulePath>
        <module>your.module.name</module>
        <output>${project.build.directory}/image</output>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Step 5: Package modules**

Package modules using `jpackage`.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.github.ghackenberg</groupId>
  <artifactId>jigsaw-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>package</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <modulePath>${project.build.directory}/modules</modulePath>
        <runtimeImage>${project.build.directory}/image</runtimeImage>
        <mainClass>your.module.name/your.package.Main</mainClass>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain the technical background on this a little bit:

joda-time in the version 2.9.9 as given in the question is a non-modular jar it does not contain a module-info.class and it does not declare itself as an automatic module by using a Automatic-Module-Name: in its META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Classes in a real module can not call classes on the classpath thus you can not use the "requires jode.time" in your module-info with that version.

Automatic Modules can use classes on the ClassPath. In order to use Classes from an non-modular jar in a real module you can use a wrapper which itself is an automatic module.

By the time now there exists a version 2.10.1 of joda-time which is an automatic module and declares "Automatic-Module-Name: org.joda.time" thus you can use an "requires org.joda.time" in your real module with that new version.

Now the new jlink tool can not operate directly with non-modular jars or automatic jars and the maven-jlink plugin currently is basically just a maven wrapper around the jlink tool translating its configuration parameters into arguments for the jlink tool.

In order to create a custom Java Runtime for projects using mixed maven dependencies with real modules, automatic modules and non-modular jars you have to know all system module dependencies of your real-modules, automatic-modules and non-modular jars and than use a --add-modules parameter to jlink with these.

To collect the system module dependencies you can use the new jdeps tool with either the --print-module-deps or --list-deps parameter depending on the actual JDK Version being used.

If you are using maven for your project you can automate that task by creating or using a maven plugin that does this for you.