# creating module-info for automatic modules with jdeps in java 9

Tags: jar, java-9, java-module, jdeps

I have 3 jar of jackson library

1. jackson-core-2.8.10.jar
2. jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
3. jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar

I created module-info.java for both core and annotation successfully and converted them to Named maodule using jdeps.

for databind , I tried following command:

> jdeps --generate-module-info . --module-path %JAVA_HOME%\jomds;jackson.core;jackson.annotations existingmods\jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar

Now following error is occuring :

```
Missing dependence: .\jackson.databind\module-info.java not generated
Error: missing dependencies
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector -> com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator       not found
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector -> com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator$Mode  not found
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector -> com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat        not found
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector -> com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value  not found
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector -> com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties not found
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector -> com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties$Value not found.
```

How can I generate module-info.java for jackson-databind ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is-there-a-way-to-add-maven-dependencies-while-using-the-maven-jlink-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103221/is-there-a-way-to-add-maven-dependencies-while-using-the-maven-jlink-plugin)? Considering maven as a framework in the other question isn't the cause of the failure.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The short answer is that, yes, you'll have to convert the libraries to explicit modules.

The `jlink` tool is intended to provide a trimmed binary image that has only the required modules. The issue is that *automatic modules* have access to the classpath (aka the unnamed module) which can read all JDK modules. So nothing would be trimmed.

[This thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2016-July/008557.html) states this as well, with a link to a YouTube video.

[This example](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_9/tree/master/egg_21_JLink_With_Converted_Jar) converts `commons-lang3-3.5.jar` to an explict module for a `jlink` demo.

**Edit**: to be more specific, [here is an example](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_9/tree/master/egg_34_stack_overflow_47727869) script that converts, in order, `jackson-core`, `jackson-annotations`, and `jackson-databind` legacy jars to modular jars.

The idea is:

- run `jdeps --generate-module-info` on the legacy jar
- unzip the legacy jar into a folder, add `module-info.java` from above, re-compile, and re-zip

The trick is that modular jars with dependencies will require those dependencies as command-line parameters. For example, here is `jackson-databind` (abstracted somewhat):

```
# here, jackson-core and jackson-annotations have been built
# jackson-databind 

jdeps --module-path $ROOT_DIR/modules \
--add-modules jackson.annotations,jackson.core \
--generate-module-info work $JACKSON_DATABIND_JAR

javac --module-path $ROOT_DIR/modules \
--add-modules jackson.annotations,jackson.core \
-d $ROOT_DIR/classes module-info.java
```

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to a GitHub solution that converts all three jars.

Comment: Although I made all the jars moduler but still jackson.databind is not reading jackson.annotation module while creating module-info.java using jdeps.

Comment: I am manually adding requires transitive jackson.annotations to module-info.java for jackson.databind

Comment: Recompiling is unnecessary. You can [inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222226/how-to-inject-module-declaration-into-jar) a module declaration into the JAR.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer describes to create Java 9 module info for libraries that do not provide it (they are treated as automatic modules).

Jackson, starting with version 2.10.0, actually provides Java 9 module info.