# Using jlink with automatic modules

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system, jlink, module-info, jdeps

I have an explicit modular project which is dependent on an automatic module; e.g. on java.activation. Is it still possible to use jlink?

See this module-info.java:

```java
module hello {
    requires java.activation;
}
```

Then jlink can't add the module:

```sh
$ jlink --module-path target/modules --add-modules hello --output target/jlink
Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: java.activation from file:///C:/Development/jlinkExample/target/modules/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
```

From my understanding, an automatic module would contain the whole classpath anyway. So I guess there would be no benefit to creating a runtime image with jlink?

See also: [What is an automatic module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module)

Are there any possibilities to circumvent this issue? Maybe generating a module-info.java for those dependencies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> From my understanding an automatic module would contain the whole
> classpath anyway, so I guess there would be no benefit in creating a
> runtime-image with jlink?

No, automatic modules would not contain the whole classpath. In fact, the artifacts which are not explicitly defined as modules(contain `module-info.java`) but are found on the **modulepath** are treated as automatic modules to bridge the gap between explicit modules and the classpath code.

> Are there any possibilities to circumvent this issue, maybe generating
> a module-info for those dependencies?

Yes, you can either [create a `module-info.java` with `jdeps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727869/creating-module-info-for-automatic-modules-with-jdeps-in-java-9) or use plugins like [moditect](https://github.com/moditect/moditect) to generate module-info for the module and inject it in your existing JAR.

Once the artifact(JAR) has an explicit module declaration, `jlink` should accept it without failure.