# Downloading file using SFTP in modular project?

Tags: java, maven

I am working right now on a java project and when trying to build a .jar with a self contained JRE I discovered jlink. When trying to make jlink work I learned about modular project so I tried to convert my project to a modular project. For now my project runs without error as a modular project when running `mvn javafx:run` (I use javafx for the UI) but when I try to run `mvn javafx:jlink` I get this error :

`Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: jsch from file:///C:/dev2/maven3/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.55/jsch-0.1.55.jar`

After some research and testing I understood that to use a library in a modular project it has to have a module-info but it seems that Jsch, sshj and apache commons net don't comply to this requirement.

My question : I want to download some file from a STFP server, how can I do that in a modular project? Do I need to find a different library?

Comment: maybe this question helps: [Using jlink with automatic modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52518105/85421) or similar obtained by searching for ["\[java\] automatic module jlink"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+automatic+module+jlink). Otherwise, yes, you will need to find another library :-/