# How to use JNI_CreateJavaVM to run modular java app

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java-11, java-platform-module-system, jnienv

I'm porting our native windows app launcher from Java 8 to Java 11. We used to call `JNI_CreateJavaVM` method to instantiate a JVM instance, find main class and call its `main` method. With a modular app, `env->FindClass` doesn't return our app class. I tried calling `Class.forName` and it doesn't return a class instance as well.

Also, `JNI_CreateJavaVM` complaints about `--add-modules` argument.

How should we specify modules to load for the JNI api?

What can I do to find the app class from the native part?

Comment: I published an answer to this in this Stackoverflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781048/module-path-in-c-to-java-jni-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to run a Java app using JLI api instead. I used this code to invoke JLI api:
https://github.com/MovingBlocks/TerasologyJavaLauncher/blob/master/jli_library_win.cpp

It seems that a hack with app hooks isn't necessary anymore. I tried with JDK 11.0.2 and it worked correctly "as-is" without hacking jli.dll path.