# Error: "Package is declared 'javafx.beans.value' in module 'foo.bar'"

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system, java-11, javafx-11

I've developed a library which `module-info.java` looks like that:

```
module foo.bar {
  requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
  requires javafx.base;
  requires java.validation;
  exports foo.bar;
}
```

This library is used in another project where the `module-info.java` contains the following:

```
module other.project {
  requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
  requires javafx.base;
  requires javafx.graphics;
  requires javafx.fxml;
  requires foo.bar;
}
```

When I try to use `import javafx.beans.value.WritableValue;` I get the error

> Package `javafx.beans.value` is declared in `foo.bar`, which does not
>   export it to module `other.project`.

**UPDATE:** I created two example projects which reproduce the problem. Please find them [here](http://www.filedropper.com/ideaprojects) to download.

I do not understand why that is and yet I could not find a solution.

Comment: Can you post the full exception? Did you manage to get each of the modules running standalone, without having dependencies between them?

Comment: @JoséPereda I do not get an exception as such, it is just a info provided by IDEA - please see https://img.picload.org/image/dcoogipr/snippet.png

Comment: And did you try your modules as standalone? Do you build/run them normally?

Comment: module 'foo.bar' works stand-alone, the other one I cannot test since 'foo.bar' is a strict dependency.

Comment: I have tested two simple modules with a similar setup as yours, with Gradle on IntelliJ, no issues at all. Are you using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I am using Gradle.

Comment: I’ve tried this [sample](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Modular/Gradle), adding a new module with just an `IntegerProperty` object. No issues

Comment: Actually, I did not download any OpenJFX JDK for my project, just the Gradle dependencies.

Comment: You don’t need them, Gradle manages that for you. Make sure that you have the right classifier. Can you run that HelloFX sample as is?

Comment: Yes, the HelloFX works fine for me. As soon as I remove the dependency of my other lib I can use the JFX libs. But apparently there is a problem if both my project and the external lib requires the same external module.

Comment: 1. *This library is used in another project*...is it used as an *automatic module* or an *explicit module*? 2. Does adding a VM arg `--add-exports foo.bar/javafx.beans.value=other.project` makes it work?

Comment: @nullpointer 1. I am not sure if I know what the difference is. 2. That is what IDEA suggest me to do and it makes it work.

Comment: @Hannes for (1) can you share a [complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that's the only way I know to figure out the exact cause of the error you see?

Comment: @nullpointer Sure, please find it here: http://www.filedropper.com/ideaprojects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the project posted [here](http://www.filedropper.com/ideaprojects), the error that you get when you open the project is:

> Package 'javafx.beans.property' is declared in module 'com.example.external.lib', which does not export it to module 'example.project'

The reason for this error is that you are adding some packages from `javafx.base` to your external library, but those are not exported to the project that uses this library. The `javafx.beans.property` package is internally used by the external module, but *it can't be exported*.

So these are some proposed changes to make it work.

If you are creating a modular jar (using a `module-info` class) as a dependency for another project, you don't need to use the shadow plugin, and you don't need to *bundle* the JavaFX dependencies in your jars.

1. External-library project

So you can have the same `module-info.java` file:

```
module com.example.external.lib {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires org.apache.commons.lang3;

    exports com.example.external.library;
}
```

with a `build.gradle` like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.osdetector'
apply plugin: 'java'

ext.platform = osdetector.os == 'osx' ? 'mac' : osdetector.os == 'windows' ? 'win' : osdetector.os

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11:$platform"
}

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.base'
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, when you run `gradle build`, you will generate `libs/external-library.jar`, a 2 KB jar, without JavaFX dependencies.

Note that if you still want to do shadow jar with this external project, you can use `compileOnly "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11:$platform"` to keep the JavaFX dependencies out of this jar.

2. Project-using-external-lib

You can add that jar to the project.

`build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.osdetector'
apply plugin: 'java'

ext.platform = osdetector.os == 'osx' ? 'mac' : osdetector.os == 'windows' ? 'win' : osdetector.os

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/external-library.jar')
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11:$platform"
}

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.base'
        ]
    }
}
```

But now your `module-info` file should include again the `javafx.base` dependency:

```
module example.project {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires com.example.external.lib;

    exports com.example.project;
}
```

You can run `gradle build` to generate a jar, and IntelliJ won't complain anymore.

If you want to have a shadow jar at the end, you can also apply:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.osdetector'

ext.platform = osdetector.os == 'osx' ? 'mac' : osdetector.os == 'windows' ? 'win' : osdetector.os

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/external-library.jar')
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11:$platform"
}

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.base'
        ]
    }
}

run {
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.base'
        ]
    }
}

mainClassName = "com.example.project.PublicClass"

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.project.PublicClass'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

so you would be able to run `java -jar build/libs/project-using-external-lib.jar`. Note that this jar will contain the JavaFX classes.

Doing a shadow jar is not to the recommended way to distribute your project, but since you have automatic modules (commons-lang3) you can't use `jlink`, unless you convert that into an explicit module (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47728002/3956070)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - that worked out for me on the small example project. But I am not quite sure how to progress with my large codebase depending on a larger number of external libraries which have not been modularized yet. Any thoughts on that? I opened another question regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314512/jigsaw-bundling-jre-with-automatic-modules

Comment: I'd say you can do a combination of a fat jar for all non-modular dependencies, with a custom JRE with all the modular dependencies via jlink. Jpackager is around the corner, and that will allow creating an installer for your app, no matter if it has non-modular dependencies. Internally, by the way, is uses jlink, so it works pretty much as I described before.

Comment: As mentioned at the end of my answer, there are also some "tricky" ways to generate modules out of non modular jars. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727869/creating-module-info-for-automatic-modules-with-jdeps-in-java-9), and this [repo](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_9/tree/master/egg_34_stack_overflow_47727869). This might help you to modularize jars that won't be ever modularized.

Comment: Well, I believe I am stuck ... that tricky way is nice if you have one or two dependencies but it is not possible to maintain that for a larger amount of libraries. Is there any roadmap if and when jpacker will be available?

Comment: There is a [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343) for it, the initial target is Java 12, but it might not make it on time. Anyway, Gluon is working on a ea release for Java 11.