# Jigsaw: Bundling JRE with Automatic Modules

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system, java-11

Is there a way to bundle the JRE with `jlink` if not all or even none of the application's dependencies are yet modularized?

I do understand that this does not lead to trimmed runtimes but still, I want to bundle a JRE with my application, even untrimmed.

Comment: Partly. If you know what Java-modules your application needs, you can use jlink to create a reduced JRE with only these modules. Just use --add-modules to list the needed Java-modules.

Comment: @RalfRenz What if I do not know because it is a larger application with a lot of external dependencies? Is there a way to add everything as a module?

Comment: I thought the reason to use jlink was to reduce the JRE to the modules that are needed. If you need everything than just put a JRE and your application together and make sure that the application uses this JRE.

Comment: @RalfRenz AFIK that is not the Java 11 way to go.

Comment: @Hannes I would second that. Also, IMHO to bring this in a discussion a better place would be [jdk-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/jdk-dev)

Comment: @nullpointer Good idea, I applied for subscription there and going to post my question there as well.