# JavaFX Maven with moditect and Java 11

Tags: maven, javafx, jlink, java-11, moditect

As per [Is there a way to add maven dependencies while using the maven-jlink-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103221/is-there-a-way-to-add-maven-dependencies-while-using-the-maven-jlink-plugin)
Has anyone used [ModiTect Maven plug-in](https://github.com/moditect/moditect) with JavaFX in Java 11.  I tried use the maven-jlink-plugin with:

```
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jlink-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha-1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version> <!-- Use newer version of ASM -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

But got:

```
--- maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-1:jlink (default-jlink) @ test33 ---
Toolchain in maven-jlink-plugin: jlink [ C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\jlink.exe ]
The following dependencies will be linked into the runtime image:
 -> module: javafx.controlsEmpty ( C:\Users\md\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\11-ea+25\javafx-controls-11-ea+25.jar )
 -> module: javafx.controls ( C:\Users\md\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\11-ea+25\javafx-controls-11-ea+25-win.jar )
 -> module: javafx.graphicsEmpty ( C:\Users\md\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\11-ea+25\javafx-graphics-11-ea+25.jar )
 -> module: javafx.graphics ( C:\Users\md\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\11-ea+25\javafx-graphics-11-ea+25-win.jar )
 -> module: javafx.baseEmpty ( C:\Users\md\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\11-ea+25\javafx-base-11-ea+25.jar )
 -> module: javafx.base ( C:\Users\md\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\11-ea+25\javafx-base-11-ea+25-win.jar )
 -> module: javafx.fxmlEmpty ( C:\Users\md\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\11-ea+25\javafx-fxml-11-ea+25.jar )
 -> module: javafx.fxml ( C:\Users\md\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\11-ea+25\javafx-fxml-11-ea+25-win.jar )
 -> module: javafx.mediaEmpty ( C:\Users\md\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\11-ea+25\javafx-media-11-ea+25.jar )
 -> module: javafx.media ( C:\Users\md\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\11-ea+25\javafx-media-11-ea+25-win.jar )

Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: javafx.mediaEmpty from file:///C:/Users/mduso/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-media/11-ea+25/javafx-media-11-ea+25.jar
```

From reading the other post I know I have to generate module info but was hoping someone has already used ModiTect Maven plugin in their pom to do it automatically for them each time.

I am going to use JavaFX with my students in all their programs and don't want to have all of them do it manually each time for all the JavaFX modules. 

***EDITED***
I attempted this with the follow pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>md</groupId>
    <artifactId>test33</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test33</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>md.test33.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11-ea+25</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11-ea+25</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- sets up the version of Java you are running and complines the Code -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>  <!-- or <release>10</release>-->
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <!-- used to make the program run -->            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>     




            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
                <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Beta1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-module-info-to-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                            <modules>
                                <module>
                                    <moduleInfo>
                                        <name>md.test33.MainApp</name>
                                    </moduleInfo>
                                </module>
                                <module>
                                    <artifact>
                                        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>javafx.controls</artifactId>
                                        <version>11-ea+25</version>
                                    </artifact>
                               </module>
                                <module>
                                    <artifact>
                                        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>javafx.graphics</artifactId>
                                        <version>11-ea+25</version>
                                    </artifact>
                                </module>
                            </modules>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-module-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-runtime-image</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create-runtime-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <modulePath>
                                <path>${project.build.directory}/modules</path>
                            </modulePath>
                            <modules>
                                <module>md.test33.MainApp</module>
                                <module>javafx.controls</module>
                                <module>javafx.graphics</module>
                            </modules>
                            <launcher>
                                <name>test33</name>
                                <module>md.test33.MainApp</module>
                            </launcher>
                            <compression>2</compression>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jlink-image</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.moditect:moditect-maven-plugin:1.0.0.Beta1:add-module-info (add-module-info-to-dependencies) on project test33: Failure to find org.openjfx:javafx.controls:jar:11-ea+25 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.moditect:moditect-maven-plugin:1.0.0.Beta1:add-module-info (add-module-info-to-dependencies) on project test33: Failure to find org.openjfx:javafx.controls:jar:11-ea+25 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failure to find org.openjfx:javafx.controls:jar:11-ea+25 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.moditect.mavenplugin.util.ArtifactResolutionHelper.resolveArtifact(ArtifactResolutionHelper.java:77)
    at org.moditect.mavenplugin.util.ArtifactResolutionHelper.resolveArtifact(ArtifactResolutionHelper.java:57)
    at org.moditect.mavenplugin.add.AddModuleInfoMojo.resolveArtifactsToBeModularized(AddModuleInfoMojo.java:185)
    at org.moditect.mavenplugin.add.AddModuleInfoMojo.execute(AddModuleInfoMojo.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find org.openjfx:javafx.controls:jar:11-ea+25 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
    at org.moditect.mavenplugin.util.ArtifactResolutionHelper.resolveArtifact(ArtifactResolutionHelper.java:74)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.openjfx:javafx.controls:jar:11-ea+25 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 29 more
```

Any ideas anyone? Or should I wait until Java11 is fully released and hope someone adds module info to the JavaFX files?

Comment: does changing the dependency to`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
  <version>11-ea+25</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>` work? "type" specified

Comment: That didn't change anything. Same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have added a complete example for OpenJDK11 with OpenJFX 11 and auto generated modul-info.class with moditect plugin (Click [here](https://bitbucket.org/Gumara/mavenjavafx/src/moditect/)!)

Try this:

Note: The moduleName property must be the same as in the module info file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>md</groupId>
    <artifactId>test33</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test33</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>md.test33.MainApp</mainClass>
        <moduleName>md</moduleName>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11-ea+25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- sets up the version of Java you are running and complines the Code -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>  <!-- or <release>10</release>-->
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>6.2.1</version> <!-- Use newer version of ASM -->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!-- used to make the program run -->            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--module-path</argument>
                                <argument>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/modules
                                </argument> 
                                <argument>--module</argument>
                                <argument>${moduleName}/${mainClass}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>     

            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.0</version>
              <configuration>
                 <outputDirectory>
                     ${project.build.directory}/modules
                 </outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
           </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
                <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Beta1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-runtime-image</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create-runtime-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <modulePath>
                                <path>${project.build.directory}/modules</path>
                            </modulePath>
                            <modules>
                                <module>${moduleName}</module>
                                <!--   <module>javafx.controls</module>
                                <module>javafx.graphics</module> -->
                            </modules>
                            <launcher>
                                <name>test33</name>
                                <module>${moduleName}/${mainClass}</module>
                            </launcher>
                            <compression>2</compression>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jlink-image</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

modul-info.java

```
module md { 
  requires javafx.fxml; 
  requires javafx.controls; 
  requires javafx.graphics; 
  requires javafx.base; 
  opens md.test33; 
}
```

Comment: got the following:--- moditect-maven-plugin:1.0.0.Beta1:create-runtime-image (create-runtime-image) @ test33 ---
Error: Module md.test33.MainApp not found
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.moditect:moditect-maven-plugin:1.0.0.Beta1:create-runtime-image (create-runtime-image) on project test33: Execution create-runtime-image of goal org.moditect:moditect-maven-plugin:1.0.0.Beta1:create-runtime-image failed: Execution of jlink failed -> [Help 1]

Comment: Do you have a modul-info file in your project? It should look something like this:
     `module md {
         requires javafx.fxml;
         requires javafx.controls;
         requires javafx.graphics;
         requires javafx.base;
         requires java.logging;
         opens md.test33.MainApp;
     }`

Comment: isn't the moditect plugin supposed to make it for me.  I am building this program in netbeans and don't know where to put the module-info into it.

Comment: i added in the module-info.java file and was now able to get it to make the jlink-image but now the program will not run in netbeans and when I try and run it outside I get "no main manifest attribute, in test33-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

Comment: Edit in Netbeans: Project Properties --> Actions --> Run project to `exec.args=--module-path ${project.build.directory}/modules --module ${moduleName}/${mainClass}`

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli) on project test33: The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

Comment: But if I change one of the plugins to:<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: and had to add: <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive> to the maven-jar-plugin to setup the mainclass

Comment: I tried the auto generated one and it gives about 45mb more in the jlink-image. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm sorry as this is now nearly 2 years since the post was made, but I'm using the same method and it seems to work fine until I get the following error:  "Error: Two versions of module javax.inject found". Can someone help me how to fix this?