# How to inject module declaration into JAR?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, module-info

Suppose I have some library `lib.jar` for which I do not have the source code (or it is written in some non-Java language which is unaware of modules yet). `lib.jar` does not have `module-info.class` and I do not want to use it as an automatic module, so I would like to inject `module-info.class` into it.

I first generate `module-info.java` with the following command:

```
jdeps --generate-module-info . lib.jar
```

Suppose this generated something like that:

```
module lib {
    exports package1;
    exports package2;
}
```

Then I try to compile it but `javac` fails because the packages `package1` and `package2` do not exist:

```
> javac module-info.java
module-info.java:4: error: package is empty or does not exist: package1
```

Of course, I can create directories `package1` and `package2` with dummy classes in them, but is there some better approach?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the `--patch-module` option. This option is most often used at runtime, but it also works at compile time:

```
javac --patch-module <module name>=<path to jar> module-info.java
```

Comment: when I use this command, I still get the error:
> javac module-info.java
module-info.java:4: error: package is empty or does not exist: package1

Any ideia why it might not working for me?

Comment: @TiagoSantos Does the package exist in the JAR?

Comment: yes, everything seems fine, I managed to have it working using the solution above from nullpointer, I do agree that your solution is more elegant, the only problem is that isn't working with my .jars :/ tried in 2 different ones

Comment: @TiagoSantos Have you replaced `lib` with the actual module name?

Comment: @TiagoSantos I modified my answer because that was indeed unobvious that `lib` should be substituted with the module name.

Comment: ahhh! indeed was not obvious :D thanks for the update

Comment: For anyone attempting to update a legacy JAR with a generated module-info, this sequence of commands is what I got to work:

`jdeps --generate-module-info . <jar_path>`
`javac --patch-module <module_name>=<jar_path> <module_name>/module-info.java`
`jar uf <jar_path> -C <module_name> module-info.class`

Comment: The addition by Philip is important, as the command in the answer does not inject anything but only compiles module-info.java into module-info.class for a jar. The class is then added to the jar using jar command.

Comment: This worked for me also. I used it for JSoup jar and the module-info.java was effectively empty, other the the name of org.jsoup. I using this with JPackage.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, to compile the `module-info.java` generated you need to also extract the contents of the JAR to a directory.

Then compile the `module-info.java` with the output directory (-d) set to the directory where you extracted the contents.

***[Credits :- Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103221/is-there-a-way-to-add-maven-dependencies-while-using-the-maven-jlink-plugin#comment81159146_47103359)***

Comment: I accepted my own answer because I think my way is slightly more elegant. Extracting files is an extra step which is a bit inconvenient (especially for tools).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven and the original library is available there, you can use the `add-module-info` goal of the [moditect plugin](https://github.com/moditect/moditect). Below is a snippet of pom.xml I used to patch the h2 jdbc driver and engine. The plugin creates a patched copy of the plugin in `${project.build.directory}/modules` which can then be used e.g. jlinked in.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
    <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-module-infos</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-module-info</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                <modules>
                    <module>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                            <version>2.1.214</version>
                        </artifact>
                        <moduleInfoSource>
                            module com.h2database {
                            requires java.compiler;
                            requires jdk.net;
                            requires static lucene.core;
                            requires static lucene.queryparser;
                            requires static slf4j.api;
                            requires static jakarta.servlet;
                            requires transitive java.desktop;
                            requires transitive java.instrument;
                            requires java.logging;
                            requires transitive java.management;
                            requires static java.naming;
                            requires transitive java.scripting;
                            requires java.sql;
                            requires transitive java.transaction.xa;
                            requires transitive java.xml;
                            requires static javax.servlet.api;
                            requires static org.locationtech.jts;
                            requires static org.osgi.service.jdbc;
                            requires static osgi.core;
                            provides java.sql.Driver with org.h2.Driver;
                            }
                        </moduleInfoSource>
                    </module>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```