# javac package not found or does not exist

Tags: java, java-module, jlink, apache-commons-cli, java-12

I have a project written in Java 12 (fairly new to java9+ and using modules) and I want to use jlink to create a custom runtime image. I also want to use apache.commons.cli as a 3rd party library for my project. How can I make use of automatic modules and compile in order to create a jlink image?

I am getting errors like so:

tmp\commons.cli\module-info.java:3: error: package is empty or does not exist: org.apache.commons.cli
    exports org.apache.commons.cli;
                              ^
1 error

My structure is as follows:

`C:.
├───.settings
├───bin
│   └───com
│       └───ngdesk
├───src
│   ├───com
│   │   └───ngdesk
│   └───out
└───target
    ├───classes
    │   ├───com
    │   │   └───ngdesk
    │   ├───META-INF
    │   │   └───maven
    │   │       └───ngDesk-ControlApp
    │   │           └───ngDesk-ControlApp
    │   └───out
    └───test-classes`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add maven dependencies while using the maven-jlink-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103221/is-there-a-way-to-add-maven-dependencies-while-using-the-maven-jlink-plugin)

Comment: Do take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48408454/java-9-generating-a-runtime-image-with-jlink-using-3rd-party-jars and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222226/how-to-inject-module-declaration-into-jar if you are willing to update the legacy jar.

Comment: I am still getting the error 'package is empty or does not exist: ' even though i see the package in the jar

Comment: According to the error message, the problem occurs when `tmp\commons.cli\module-info.java` is compiled, hence, it is entirely unrelated to your project and the presence of `module-info.java` indicates that `commons.cli` is not an automatic module. So you’re failing at compiling the modular `commons.cli` and anything else you’ve posted, is irrelevant.