# How to create a module-info class file and add it to the jar?

Tags: java, javafx, zxing, jlink, module-info

I am Working on a javafx project where i am in need to generate `module-info.class` file myself. So, Iam wondering how to do it properly and make it work with maven.

Iam facing this issue with a QRCode generator library `zxing`. I cannot find any alternative Qr generator libraries in java with module-info.class file , if any please mention it.

I have to do this, since i use jlink which throws "automatic module cannot be used with jlink" error.

breif explanation would be very helpful :)

note: I have tried to inject the module file using a tool but it throws error: cannot read jar

Comment: Without Maven, the basic steps are: **(1)** Generate the module-info descriptor with `jdeps` (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jdeps.html#module-dependence-analysis-options)); **(2)** Compile the module-info source file with `javac` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47222226/6395627)); **(3)** Add the module-info class file to the JAR file with `jar`.

Comment: There may be Maven plugins out there that already do this for you. For example, [moditect](https://github.com/moditect/moditect) seems to do this, though I've never used it.

Comment: If you're using Java 9 or higher, just add a `module-info.java` file to the root of your source folder (i.e. with no package), and include it in compilation. When using Maven, just put it directly in `src/main/java`. If you're using Java 8 then Moditect works great. I'm using it in my Java 8 libraries without any problems.

Comment: @RobSpoor If I understood correctly, the OP is trying to add a module-info descriptor to a non-modular third-party dependency.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you i have successfully injected the file into the library and jlink is working perfectly. I'm getting some errors after running my application from the generated zip file from jlink i'll figure it out

Comment: @jewelsea ok i'll do it

Comment: @Dharun no `module-info.class` should be needed; zxing defines an automatic module name in its manifest, which means it can be used as an automatic module. You can include it in your own module-info (for the core library it's `com.google.zxing`). All packages are exported. The only thing you won't be getting is transient module dependencies, so you'd have to add those to your own module-info.

Comment: @Rob Spoor jlink throws an error that says "automatic module cannot be used with jlink"   that's why i had to inject the module-info file and everything works fine now. I haven't tried adding those transient dependencies to my own module-info file i might try it later thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fed up with module injector tools so ,I tried to do it with jdeps

Follow these simple step to inject the module-info properly

1. Copy the jar file (in my case zxing package i.e core-3.4.1.jar) into a folder (here i copied it into `libs` folder)
2. open cmd and navigate to **parent folder** of libs folder .

now run the command,

```
jdeps --ignore-missing-deps --generate-module-info libs libs/core-3.4.1.jar
```

It creates a module-info.java inside libs folder or inside one with its module name(in my case `com.google.zxing/module-info.java`).

3. copy the module-info.java file and paste it inside the libs folder
4. Run the command,

```
javac --patch-module com.google.zxing=jars/core-3.4.1.jar jars/module-info.java
```

it will generate the module-info.class file in the libs folder.

5. Now to inject the file into the jar,run

```
jar uf jars/core-3.4.1.jar -C jars module-info.class
```

Now your module-info.class file will be injected inside the jar which you can use it in you modular javafx project

note: Don't do this unless there is no option. In my case iam using the zxing library to generate QR code and i couldn't find a good alternative for it.

Comment: There should not be a need no need to do any patching, zxing core is an automatic module. All packages are exported, only the transitive dependencies are missing and need to be added to the project's own `module-info.java` if those are needed.

Comment: @RobSpoor Automatic modules can make it extremely difficult to build native packages though. This may be an easier option if the OP wants to build a modular application with `jlink` and/or `jpackage`.

Comment: @RobSpoor Automatic modules cannot be used with `jlink`, even if the JAR's manifest has an `Automatic-Module-Name` entry. It's not clear in the question body that `jlink` is being used, but the question _is_ tagged with [tag:jlink]. That said, non-modular code can be packaged with `jpackage` with the `--input` option, but that may not be desirable, or even an option, for the OP.