# No suitable driver found for sqlite in a runtime image java

Tags: java, image, sqlite, maven, javafx

I'm working on a Maven JavaFX project with sqlite and my goal is to create an installer using jpackage. One of the first steps is to create a runtime image. So I was planning on creating the image, make sure that it runs and then create an installer using jpackage.

These are my dependencies in Maven:

> org.openjfx
>           javafx-controls
>           14
>       
>       
>           org.openjfx
>           javafx-fxml
>           14
>       
>       
>           org.xerial
>           sqlite-jdbc
>           3.30.1
>           jar

This is how I connect to the db:

> connection=(Connection)
>   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+getClass().getResource("database.db"));

I create the runtime image with maven:

> mvn clean javafx:jlink

And when I run the image I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:
```

I tried adding `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");` but now I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.jdbc
```

I already tried following these [instructions](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/README.md#hint-for-maven-shade-plugin) but I keep getting the same errors.

Everything works fine when I run the project using InteliJ. I've been trying to get this to work for a while now and I keep failing. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what I need to add or change?

Comment: I took a look at the GitHub page to see if it would say compatible with Java9+. I did not see that anywhere. My guess is that the jar you have is not compatible with Java9+. See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882108/how-to-find-automatic-modules-with-javapackager helps.

Answer (score -2):

I have SQLite running without problems. For building I follow this tutorial
https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX which I created together with Dirk Lemmermann. There isn't anything special to do for SQLite. If you want to use it via the Maven shade plugin or the GraalVM things get a little bit more complicated but it also works.